# SEM-Path analysis in R (standardization of variables)

Tags: r, path, analysis

I am running the plspm library in R in order to find the direct effects and the weights of my variables in my model. In :

```
sales_pls <- plspm(input_file, sales_path, sales_blocks, scheme = "centroid", scaled = TRUE, modes = sales_modes)
```

when i use scaled = True R automatically does standardization by X-μ/σ .

My question is if i normalize my data with the maximum value and set scaled = FALSE, the weights in the output will refer on the raw data which is normalized or they will refer on the standardized (X-μ/σ) data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will refer to raw data which is normalized.